# is forwarding a dopost or a doget by default?

Tags: jsp, servlets, forward, requestdispatcher

my simple question is:

by default, when i do `request.getRequestDispatcher("\someUri").forward(request, response);`

will it be a `doPost` or a `doGet` request?
and what exacly does it depend on? (assuming i didn't make wrapper class.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`doGet()`/`doPost()` depends on your request `'METHOD'` type. If it is `GET` then `doGet()`. If it is `POST` then `doPost()`.
While doing forward you are passing same request as parameter. So, that same request METHOD type decides your forward type.

Comment: okay, so the METHOD type decides the forward type, but what is the METHOD types -default- value? because i noticed there is no simple setter for this.